# Accessing url parameters in sails action

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I have a sails app, and I am agttempting to load a page with some data from a database, based on the `id` of the `recipe` model.

I have the route `'GET /recipes/single-recipe/:id':    { action: 'recipes/view-single-recipe' }` set up, and am accessing the url `http://localhost:1337/recipes/single-recipe/5b8c169936f1df3439fa39c7`

In my `view-single-recipe` action I'm attempting to load the  recipe with the id of the URL parameter by accessing `req.param('id')` but `req` is showing undefined.

```js
//view-single-recipe.js
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'View single recipe',


  description: 'Display "Single recipe" page.',


  exits: {

    success: {
      viewTemplatePath: 'pages/recipes/single-recipe'
    }

  },


  fn: async function(inputs, exits) {
    const recipe = await Recipe.find({
      id: req.param('id') //req undefiend
    });
    // Respond with view.
    return exits.success({
      recipe: recipe
    });

  }


};
```

Getting error: `error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 ReferenceError: req is not defined`

How can I load the correct recipe using the url param?

Comment: Which version of Sails are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the route ***`/recipes/single-recipe/:id'`***, then the "**`id`**" from the URL path will be available as **`req.params.id`**. Otherwise, it defaults to `{}` For more [info](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-param)

**UPDATE:**

But when it comes to **Actions and Controllers**, `Sails.js` uses the *`machine-as-action`* module to automatically create *`route-handling`* functions out of machines like the [example](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers#?actions-2) shows. See the machine-as-action docs for [more information](https://github.com/treelinehq/machine-as-action#customizing-the-response).

Note that machine-as-action provides actions with access to the **`request`** object as **`this.req`** instead of just `req`, otherwise, there'll be a server error of *`req is not defined`*. So, for future references **don't forget the `this`** keyword.

Comment: Still getting error error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 ReferenceError: req is not defined

Comment: Hmmn ... Sails is an MVC framework what I mean by that is, you have to be careful with your file names. In other words, If your model file name is Recipes.js replace xyz.create with Recipes.create

Comment: Are you using some other framework, like Express alongside with Sails?

Comment: So, you were right about what you corrected, however in an 'action' in sails it needs to be acces by `this.req` according to the docs; https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers. If you want to update your answer to include that I will accept it. thanks

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I will update it ASAP.
I'm glad I was of some help, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks, @chuckieDub for correcting my first answer. So, the question you asked is partially answered by yourself. This might help someone else in the future. Cheers :)